# How to open notepad++ of a file ON A CERTAIN LINE?

Tags: python, subprocess, notepad++

I am writing a python script that is suppose to open a txt file via Notepad ++ ON A CERTAIN LINE.
This is my code but it allows me just to open the file on the first line.

```
def open_notepad():
    subprocess.call([
        r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe",r"path_to_file.txt"
    ])
```

Comment: See https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/ more specifically the `-n` argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can add arguments to your call to `notepad++.exe`. In your case you would need to add `-n` and then an integer.

[Source documentation](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/)

For example:

```py
subprocess.call([
  "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", "-n", str(line_number), file_path
])
```

Comment: Breaking the command string up into tokens like OP originally did is good practice; it gives you good and easy control over how the strings are separated. `subprocess.call([notepad_exe, "-n", str(line_number), file_path])`

Comment: I'll amend my answer :+1:'